# How to change size of existing column using Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I have a POCO Plant that is mapped to a table dbo.Plant in my DB (SQL SERVER 2014). Some of the columns in the database has the data types nvarchar(max) NULL. I am trying to change the data type via EntityTypeConfiguration using the following code:

```
Property(x => x.PCode).HasMaxLength(25);
```

But, when adding the migration (add-migration name), the resulting Up()-method will not contain any changes for this column.
However, if I also make it required like this:

```
Property(x => x.PCode).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
```

..then the appropriate changes will be made in the Up()-method:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Plant", "PCode", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 25));
```

Is it possible to get it to register only the change in size without changing the nullability?

Edit: I have managed to come around the problem by making changes directly in the Up() and Down()-methods, but the question remains if there is anything that would trigger this change automatically just using the EntityTypeConfiguration.

Comment: You could try adding an empty migration and add   AlterColumn("dbo.Plant", "PCode", c => c.String(maxLength: 25)); to the Up() method of it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That is what I have done (should have mentioned it) to come around this, but I also would like to know if I could do this without hacking the migration. Thanks for your suggestion @thsorens

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if you change the value of the maxlength to a different number, it might generate the appropriate (correct) migration.
Had a similar issue that was generating a blank migration, for the value I wanted it to change to. So I changed the number to a different number and it did work.