# Entity Framework code first, change maxlength only, does not trigger model change

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I change my model attribute from this

`[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar"), MaxLength(8)]`

to this

`[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar"), MaxLength(32)]`

I get NO model change:

```
 public partial class V0114 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

Is there a workaround for this?

We use this version: `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />`

Ps the rest works; if I add a new property on the class all goes well and with all previous changes (in which we all had largere changes) we encountered no problems.

Ps2 it's a bugfix, so after a few hours I also 'dirty' workarounds are welcome

Comment: If you add a new property does it catch the MaxLength change as well, or just the property change?

Comment: The maxlength too: `AddColumn("dbo.relatie", "Voorletters2", c => c.String(maxLength: 22));`

Comment: Looks like a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299080/how-to-change-size-of-existing-column-using-entity-framework-6-code-first

Comment: Agreed. Which means a dirty fix is to add a property then remove the property. you would have two migrations, but at least you would get your maxLength adjustment. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a bug indeed.