# Change column in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an nvarchar in a table with the length of 6.  I created it with code first and the data notation `[StringLength(6)]`.

I want to change the length to 20. I tried to change it in the code and make a new migration but that did nothing.

Comment: What do you mean "did nothing?" Was the migration created? is it empty? Did you get an error?

Comment: The migration was created but in it was only the removal and recreation of the foreignkeys. So it did not change anything in the DB

Comment: I recall that being a bug. You can add the needed code to Up(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299080/how-to-change-size-of-existing-column-using-entity-framework-6-code-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to do it with code first. The only way that worked for me was to make a query on the Database direcly.

```
ALTER TABLE [Tablename] ALTER COLUMN [Columname] nvarchar(20).
```

I had the concern that this would throw an exception because of the DatabaseContextModelSnapshot file but it worked fine. If you do this approach I would recommend to also make the changes in code and to make a new Migration for it. It is not necessary but that way your migrations & code are consistent with the Database.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do,Use Fluent Api to change your column name in onModelCreating() method.
this method can be override in your class where your are inheriting from DbContext class.

[image: screenshot to modify your column name]