# Change of StringLength attribute not included in Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, oracle12c

I had a field with following attributes:

```
[Column("Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The migration for this field looked like this:

```
CreateTable(
"dbo.TEST",
c => new
{
     Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
     Name = c.String(maxLength: 50),
})
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
.Index(t => t.Id
);
```

Then I changed the field like this:

```
[Column("Test_Name")]
[StringLength(255)]
public string TestName { get; set; }
```

and executed `Add-Migration`, but the `StringLength` change was not included it is still `NVARCHAR2(50)` in my Oracle DB and the new migration looks like this:

```
RenameColumn(table: "dbo.TEST", name: "Name", newName: "Test_Name");
```

Is this a common problem?

What do I need to do so that the length is also changed in the DB?

Comment: You may need to hack the Up() code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299080/how-to-change-size-of-existing-column-using-entity-framework-6-code-first

Answer (score 0):

How many migrations do you have already? We started to experience bugs in the creation of migration scripts after accumulating ~20 migrations. If you have more than 10 migrations try to [consolidate them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451879/1042934). When I did the consolidation the generation of migration scripts started to work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know but I only have 5 so far.

Comment: Just give it a try by deleting all your migrations and create a green field inital one to see if it is because of the bug in EF.